# FormsAuthenticationTicket and DateTime

Tags: datetime, forms-authentication

I'm just a little confused about something.  When creating forms authentication tickets I have been using this code.

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                 userName,
                 DateTime.Now,
                 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                 rememberMe,
                 userData,
                 FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```

My question is this.  Should I use DateTime.Now as this example shows or DateTime.UtcNow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server uses this values to detect session expiration. So it has to be the same timezone on creating ticket and on checking it. Use `DateTime.Now`.

Btw, if applicable to your case, it's easier to do

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);
```

Comment: But should it not be the same as the server time i.e. DateTime.Now?

Comment: @SachinKainth you are right, i got a little carried away, as server checks expiration automatically, it has to be local time.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken, but I believe you should be using DateTime.UtcNow, because based on this source code, the Expired flag checks against UTC.  Now there is a big block of comments that explains when they attempt to convert a local time to UTC, but the first line of this comments states:

> We always prefer UTC expiration dates to work around issues like a
>   daylight time changes between the time the ticket was issued and the
>   time the ticket was checked. If we have a firm UTC expiration date,
>   just use it directly.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationTicket.cs,84

So I would suggest passing DateTime.UtcNow to the Ticket constructor.

Comment: Thank for adding this comment. It appears you can pass either DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow and the date is converted. However, it appears that it is a lot safe to use DateTime.UtcNow.